# Reputation change indicator causes horizontal scrolling on mobile

Tags: bug, top-bar, mobile-web

When you get more then 100 reputation change, the green label with points doesn't fit mobile view and causes horizontal scrolling.

Tested on Firefox Mobile 67.

[image: rep change]

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you're right it's horizontal scrolling...

Comment: This is a humble brag to show off your reputation changes isn't it? You sneaky.